# How do you send a binary file to a webservice using Axis2?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I was using [Axis 1.4](http://axis.apache.org/axis) on a project and I am moving to [Axis2 1.6.3](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/). I am asking this because in **Axis1.4** it was quite straightforward :

```
myStub.addAttachment(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("path_to_file")));
```

You just add a **DataHandler** to the Stub and then send it. But in **Axis2** it seems that this method doesn't exist. So I was wondering what is the new way of attaching a DataHandler to a stub ?

As I was searching on the internet, I find out that you have to attach the DataHandler to the `MessageContext` ([Downloading a Binary File from a Web Service using Axis2 and SOAP with Attachments](http://wso2.com/library/1675/)).

So I did As it is said :

```
MessageContext messageContext = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
OperationContext operationContext = messageContext.getOperationContext(); 
MessageContext outMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_OUT_VALUE);
outMessageContext.addAttachment(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("path_to_file")));
```

But the problem is that `MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext()` return null. I think that it is not working because this snippet should be used on the server side. What I want is to be able to send a file to the server not retrieve one from the server.

I might be missing something. Maybe this is not the way to do it, anyway any help is appreciated. In the meantime I'll keep up searching on the internet and if I find something I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I figured out how to do it on Axis2 Documentation.

Go to [SOAP with Attachments (SwA) with Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html#a3) and on the second section named **Sending SwA Type Attachments**. Here you will find out how to send a file to the server.

This is the code snippet they provide :

```
public void uploadFileUsingSwA(String fileName) throws Exception {

    Options options = new Options();
    options.setTo(targetEPR);
    options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ENABLE_SWA, Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
    options.setTransportInProtocol(Constants.TRANSPORT_HTTP);
    options.setSoapVersionURI(SOAP11Constants.SOAP_ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI);
    options.setTo(targetEPR);

    ServiceClient sender = new ServiceClient(null,null);
    sender.setOptions(options);
    OperationClient mepClient = sender.createClient(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);

    MessageContext mc = new MessageContext();   
    mc.setEnvelope(createEnvelope());
    FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource("test-resources/mtom/test.jpg");
    DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(fileDataSource);
    mc.addAttachment("FirstAttachment",dataHandler);

    mepClient.addMessageContext(mc);
    mepClient.execute(true);
}
```

For more information go check the page of the documentation.

Cheers !